# Which is more normal, "OK" or "オーケー"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, loanwords

Which is more normal in Japanese, "OK", or "オーケー", assuming either of them is in common usage?

I tried using the corpus on jisho.org, but the results were messed up by "OK" appearing in the English version. [Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC&from=jpn&to=eng) didn't get many matches for "オーケー", and many of them seemed to be false hits, and also got few hits for "OK" — is neither form commonly used in Japanese?

Comment: Don't forget about 「オッケー」 and the internet slang 「おｋ」 (if you want to count that at all).

Comment: @Jimmy is おｋ used outside of 日本語でおｋ?

Comment: At any slangy internet site, you may be able to see it used. I see it 2ch and NicoNico Douga sometimes, usually in response to something, like a warning at the top of a video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "normal in Japanese" you mean in writing, because "OK" can only be written Japanese.

I think this is best answered by a corpus search. The National Institute for Japanese Language and Linguistics provides an annotated version of the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese, giving the following results:

> 4241 results in total
>
> - OK
>     3849 results (91%)
> - オーケー
>     200 results (5%)
> - オッケー
>     100 results (2%)
> - オーケイ
>     43 results (1%)
> - おｋ
>     38 results (1%)
> - オッケ
>     8 results
> - おーけー
>     3 results

To do this yourself, go to http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/search/, search for `オーケー` taking you to http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/N.00969/; go to the `基本` tab and expand `書字形`.

Answer (score 2):

They are both used commonly and we use either one depending on situation. Anyway, they are **both normal**. <del>(I think ok is normal, but this is just an ***opinion-based answer***.)</del>

---

I searched them with only Japanese pages on Google. The search results:

- OK - 118,000,000
- オーケー - 2,450,000

(I don't say this has credibility because Ok is including English sites even if I enabled that setting...)

Comment: "We use different them depending"の部分はどういう意味でしょうか。場合によって違う？人によって違う？それとも？

Comment: @broken 場合によって　です。直しました。

Answer (score 0):

The term "OK" is the casual word so there is no strict usage as far as casual usege.

"OK" is オーケー and "オーケー"　is OK!